# why pagespeed insights asks me to fix "blob" compression and cache?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, pagespeed, vuejs2, google-pagespeed

I know how to use compression and cache.

But what is blob and where does it come from?

```
blob:http%3A//35.156.214.49/34f97ab7-9c39-422a-9695-81f09dc0664b
```

You can see for yourself here:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=35.156.214.49

When i remove the vuejs manifest javascript file, the error is gone,
but i need it so vuejs will work.
Maybe i can remove that file when i compile vuejs with webpack?

Comment: No, we can't - your site is down.

Comment: it's up again..

Answer (score 0):

http://35.156.214.49/34f97ab7-9c39-422a-9695-81f09dc0664b 
resides on your site in the public_html folder. The title is bypal and has two buttons EN and JA.

The strange thing I see is there is a delay before the .webp images are loaded.  I suspect these are loaded by the javascript.  Even so you could link to them in the <`head> <style>` as background for a css rule that is not used.  It will load these images much sooner.

Add a favicon.ico

[image]